# Get content of CMS Block in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, cms-block

i want get content in CMS Block, i tryed this code but it not show content

My code :

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
     <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

It not show content, but show this:

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="gs_business_terms"}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to echo content of cms block

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
     <?php echo Mage::helper('cms')->getPageTemplateProcessor()->filter($_a->getContent());?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

You can call like this one.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
     <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId($_a->getIdentifier())->toHtml(); 
?> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```